# Compute the integral $\int_{A} x^m y^n z^p (1-x-y-z)^q dx dy dz$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Let $A =$ {$(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 |$  $x,y,z \geq 0$ and $x+y+z \leq 1$}.

Compute the integral $$\int_{A} x^m y^n z^p (1-x-y-z)^q dx dy dz$$

using new variables $u = x+y+z$, $v=\frac{y+z}{x+y+z}$, $w=\frac{z}{y+z}$.

Also, although it was not stated in the problem, I'm assuming that $m,n,p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Since $f(x,y,z)=(x+y+z, \frac{y+z}{x+y+z}, \frac{z}{y+z}) = (u,v,w)$, $f^{-1}(u,v,w) = (u(1-v), uv(1-w), uvw)$

Thus **J** $= \begin{vmatrix}
1-v & -u & 0\\ 
v(1-w) & u(1-w) & -uv\\ 
vw & uw & uv\\
\end{vmatrix} = u^2v$

Skipping the part where I find the new limits of integration, and skipping some algebraic simplification we have:

$$\int_{A} x^m y^n z^p (1-x-y-z)^q dx dy dz$$

$$= \int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^1 u^{m+n+p+2}(1-u)^q v^{n+p+1}(1-v)^mw^p(1-w)^n du dv dw$$

However, I have no  idea where to go from here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate:

$$\int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^1 u^{m+n+p+2}(1-u)^q v^{n+p+1}(1-v)^mw^p(1-w)^n \,\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}v\,\mathrm{d}w$$

$$\int_0^1 u^{m+n+2}(1-u)^q\,\mathrm{d}u ~ \int_0^1 v^{n+p+1}(1-v)^m\,\mathrm{d}v ~\int_0^1 w^p(1-w)^n\,\mathrm{d}w. $$

See [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

(Disclaimer: I did not check your work to get to the penultimate triple integral.)

Answer (score 1):

@arctic tern beat me to it by seconds, so I'll point out another method: the inner integral is
$$\int_0^{1-y-z}x^m(1-x-y-z)^qdx=\left.x^m\frac{-1}{q+1}(1-x-y-z)^{q+1}\right|_0^{1-y-z}+\frac m{q+1}\int_0^{1-y-z}x^{m-1}(1-x-y-z)^{q+1}dx$$
Since the integrated term vanishes at the endpoints we repeat until $x^m$ is completely differentiated away and repeat with the y and z integrals to get
$$\frac{m!q!}{(q+m+1)!}\cdot\frac{n!(q+m+1)!}{(q+m+n+2)!}\cdot\frac{p!(q+m+n+2)!}{(q+m+n+p+3)!}=\frac{m!q!n!p!}{(q+m+n+p+3)!}$$
which is the same as the beta functions evaluate to.